# How can I access FAT formatted USB drive on PC without operating system messing up the contents?

Tags: windows, usb, fat32

I have FAT formatted USB drives with possibly file system level problem. When I plug-in the drive to Windows system, it seems to change something on the drive erasing the problem. That makes it impossible to analyze the problem.

**How can I investigate the USB drive without operating system changing the contents silently?** I want to be able to access the disk files, and read/write disk images.

Problem happens on Windows 10, but maybe any Windows solution simply cannot work?

Comment: What is the problem and what seems to be changed by Windows on the drive?

Comment: Create a sector by sector disk image using for example ddrescue.

Comment: @harrymc I can verify that before using drive on Windows, error is on drive when using it on embedded device, but simply plugging it once to Windows makes that error go away. I don't know what Windows changed, because by doing so I lost the issue.

Comment: Questions: (1) Do you mean that there was an error condition when connected to the embedded device that disappeared after connecting to a PC? (2) Does it now work without error on the embedded device? (3) Do you remember what the error was?

Comment: @harrymc (1) Yes. (2) Yes. (3) Error on drive causes causes hang or very slow operation on embedded device.

Comment: Do you know which version of FAT was it (FAT/FAT16/FAT32)? When was this device formatted and by which version of Windows?

Comment: @harrymc I don't want to go too deep on the actual device issue here yet. There's a lot of things I need to investigate first myself, and getting stable PC enviroment to do that is my number one priority at the moment. But I do appreciate your effort to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I doubt that Windows makes some repair to the file system that allows a temporary mount, and that it forgets about until next boot. I assert that if Windows does some file system repair, it will be permanently written to the drive.

Anyway, to answer the question:

- Create a sector by sector disk image using for example ddrescue. Linux is far less 'invasive' than Windows when it comes to mounting file systems.
- Alternatively image from Windows while USB drive is behind a write blocker.
- If analysis needs to be done from Windows either mount the disk image using a tool like OFSMount, or use any disk editor or file recovery tool.

This is one of the many guides to using ddrescue: https://www.data-medics.com/forum/threads/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-with-bad-sectors-using-ddrescue.133/

This is a free tool you can use to mount dd-type disk images in Windows: https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

The free version of this tool contains a fully functional disk editor with many disk and file system structure templates: https://dmde.com/

HxD is just a great free file and disk editor: https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/. You could use it to do a byte-by-byte comparison between a disk image that does include the modification and one that does not.

Hard and software write blockers: https://forensics.wiki/write_blockers/

EDIT: I'll add one more Windows suggestion that should/may prevent Windows from performing the repair: Tell it to not mount external drives.

- Open elevated command prompt
- Type mountvol /n to disable the drive automount
- Type mountvol /r to scrub previous drive letters that were assigned during automatic mounting
- To at some point enable automounting again type mountvol /e

After giving the commands, reboot.

Problem with this method (or the DiskPart equivalent procedure) is that it some times does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: *"I assert that if Windows does some file system repair, it will be permanently written to the drive."* Yes, it is permanent change. Once drive is plugged in Windows, it is fixed from that point on.

Comment: Well, that *is* interesting, I hope you can pinpoint that change/repair and share. I'll add one more Windows suggestion that *may* work.

Comment: My current theory is that Windows writes something to hidden system folder on the drive, which possibly rewrites and fixes FAT entries. If that is the case, Linux and ddrescue seems like a way to go. Thank you, the answer has been is really helpful.

Comment: Hmm. I'd first look at for example changes in boot sector. Or, does this drive have a MBR/partition table? Does this embedded device throw an error and if so what?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I don't know details of the actual problem yet, so it's time for me to do the detective work now.

Answer (score 0):

There is one correction that Windows will do automatically, and that's
the `chkdsk` of a disk that wasn't dismounted correctly.

Even if the `chkdsk` didn't run for some reason or because of manual
intervention, the problem will be corrected when the computer will
later correctly dismount the disk.

I think that the disk wasn't properly dismounted on its last use.
For some reason the embedded system wasn't unable to correct the error,
or perhaps it displayed an error message that was never handled, and this
was the problem.

When the disk was later mounted on a PC, it was then correctly dismounted,
which cleared out the condition and fixed the problem for the embedded
system.

If that was the problem, it's important to properly dismount and eject
disks that are destined to be used on this embedded system.